# cannot install android-server.apk in mobile

Tags: android, android-emulator, webdriver, adb

i'm trying to install android-server.apk as instructed in [this link](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver).
I've created an emulator and successfully installed apk on it. But when I tried to install the same in mobile it is throwing error as

```
error: protocol fault <no status>
- waiting for device-
rm failed for /data/local/tmp/android-server.apk, No such file or directory
```

i've checked "USB debugging", "Stay Awake" and "Allow mock locations" options in my phone and my usb port has write permissions. I am using samsung s3 with windows.

Comment: "protocol fault" usually suggests some out of sync Android development tools. Use the SDK Manager to make sure that you are on the latest tools, and make sure that you only have one copy of the Android SDK (i.e., not one used by Eclipse and a separate one used at the command line).

Comment: thnks.. i have uninstalled the android sdk from eclipse and tried to install apk again in my mobile.. but still am getting the same error.. using android 4.1.2 os and sdk manager version is r22..